# Dual Boot - Boot Black Screen From an 'update' from Kubuntu 14.04 to Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, upgrade, kubuntu, nvidia-geforce

I downloaded the last version of Kubuntu **(16.04)** and installed in my laptop (Asus Rog G551j with a GeForce GTX960m video card) from a USB Stick.

The first thing I noticed, is that the version that was installed was Kubuntu **14.04**. Everything worked fine (even the nvidia drivers).

Then i run the update manager (muon) and it updated the OS with Kubuntu **15.04**. Everything worked fine (even the nvidia drivers).

I applied the same operation to upgrade to **16.04**. And that's all my problems began: when i reboot after upgrade, when the os is booting (after the kubuntu splash image) the screen remains black.

I tried to add the "nomodeset" and "noveau.modeset=0" lines in grub and other things that are explained in

[Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics)

but nothing works. =(

Comment: If the installed version is 14.04 then the installation media you used is 14.04. You may have selected the wrong one here : http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your home folder encrypted?

I used to have an issue with black screen, but that was because I couldn't see letters asking me the password to decrypt my harddisk... Because the screen was blacked out.

I got past this by just entering my password and pressing return.

Afterwards, you can fix this by setting `nouveau.modeset=0` in grub and installing the proper, proprietary Nvidia driver.